# How to turn this object to dot-notation?, so I can call multiple methods on a single line

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to OOP and still learning new techniques every time, and this is one of my tasks that I tend to do as daily basis for learning better...

Anyway, back to question; basically I've this app object of which I'd like to turn it into dot-notation when calling methods...

```
var app = function() {

    var DEFAULTS = {
        websiteName: 'Stylish App',
        websiteUrl: 'http://stylishapp.ltd',
        websiteCopyright: 'Copyright ' + new Date().getFullYear() + ' ' + this.websiteName + '.',
        websiteLanguage: 'English'
    }

    var output;

    return {

        name: function() {
            return DEFAULTS.websiteName;
        },
        url: function() {
            return DEFAULTS.websiteUrl;
        },
        copyright : function() {
            return DEFAULTS.websiteCopyright;
        }

    }
}();
```

1. So I want to be able to call my methods one after the other like so;

   ```
   document.write(  app.websiteName().websiteUrl()  );
   ```

   I know it wouldn't make sense to use for this example as nobody
   prints their
       website name followed by the url, but it's an example anyway...
2. Also in my DEFAULTS object, I tried to referring back to the actual `websiteName` as for the value of `websiteCopyright`... but I get an error saying websiteName undefined, also tried `this.websiteName` as well as `DEFAULTS.websiteName`, but none of them actually worked!

Hope it makes sense to what I'm looking to achieve
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You will need to return `this` from methods that you want to chain but in your case all methods already return something so you can't chain those methods.

Comment: I think @jcubic meant to say "so you CANNOT chain those methods"

Comment: For me, the code you supplied works.

Comment: You are trying to access `websiteName` when you are returning an object with property name `name`.

Comment: @DavidTansey yes, that what I meant

Comment: It now makes clear sense, thank you all guys :) big plus +++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you're encapsulating your functionality in the module pattern anyway, those defaults could just be private variables, at which point you can just refer to other variables directly

```js
var app = function() {

    var name = 'Stylish App';
    var url = 'http://stylishapp.ltd';
    var copyright = 'Copyright ' + new Date().getFullYear() + ' ' +  name + '.';
    var language = 'English'

    return {

        name: function() {
            return name;
        },
        url: function() {
            return url;
        },
        copyright : function() {
            return copyright;
        }

    }
}();

document.write(app.name());
document.write("<br>");
document.write(app.url());
document.write("<br>");
document.write(app.copyright());
```

As for the other question, regarding this sort of syntax

```
document.write(  app.websiteName().websiteUrl()  );
```

Thats generally refered to as a ["fluent" interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) (you refer to this as [dot-notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), which is wrong), where each method call returns `this` so that the next method can be chained on.

As a convoluted example drawing on the above code:

```js
var app = function() {

        var name = 'Stylish App';
        var url = 'http://stylishapp.ltd';
        var copyright = 'Copyright ' + new Date().getFullYear() + ' ' +  name + '.';
        var language = 'English'

        return {

            writeName: function() {
                document.write(name + "<br>");
                return this;
            },
            writeUrl: function() {
                document.write(url + "<br>");
                return this;
            },
            writeCopyright : function() {
                document.write(copyright + "<br>");
                return this;
            }

        }
    }();

    app.writeName().writeCopyright();
```

Comment: Also how could I make this app object to work like jQuery, so I can call different methods one after the other, dot-notation way... thanks

Comment: WOW, thank you so much mate, I really appreciate the effort and of course thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 2):

I really wouldn't recommend doing this. You are trying to get strings, not manipulate an object. jQuery doesn't do this when you are doing something like `$('body').attr('class');`. It just returns a string.

That said, you can:

1. Return a new instance of the object (so that you avoid mutating the existing one)
2. Special case conversion to a string

Such:

```js
function App(defaults, string) {
  defaults = defaults || {};
  this.string = string || "";
  this.websiteName = defaults.websiteName || 'Stylish App';
  this.websiteUrl = defaults.websiteUrl || 'http://stylishapp.ltd';
  this.websiteCopyright = this.websiteCopyright || 'Copyright ' + new Date().getFullYear() + ' ' + this.websiteName + '.';
  this.websiteLanguage = defaults.websiteLanguage || 'English';
}

App.prototype.toString = function toString() {
  return this.string;
}

App.prototype.name = function name() {
  var string = this.string;
  if (string) {
    string += " ";
  }
  string += this.websiteName;
  return new App(this, string);
}

App.prototype.url = function url() {
  var string = this.string;
  if (string) {
    string += " ";
  }
  string += this.websiteUrl;
  return new App(this, string);
}

App.prototype.copyright = function copyright() {
  var string = this.string;
  if (string) {
    string += " ";
  }
  string += this.websiteCopyright;
  return new App(this, string);
}

var app = new App();
alert(app.name().copyright());
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate, it now makes clear sense, because what I had in mind wasn't possible because I wanted to return some data as well as referring back to the actual object so that I could chain the next method... so yes as @KJ Price, yourself and Jameic explained I now have a very clear understanding of how and when chaining becomes useful, thank you very much guys :)

Answer (score 1):

So, if a method is supposed to return something specific, then chaining would not apply to that method. Other methods that "do something" and are not expected to return anything would return `this`. Here's an example:

```js
function Person (name) {
    this.getName = function (){ return name; } //no chaining
    this.setName = function (newName) { //chaining!
        name = newName;
        return this;
    }
    this.alertName = function () { //chaining
        alert(name);
        return this;
    }
}

var dad = new Person ('Bob');

dad.setName('Bob').alertName(); //we can chain here because "this" was returned in setName method
```

Comment: Thank you mate, really appreciate your help :) yes you're right, if a method is returning something then there isn't any point of chaining them, unless I'm trying to alert or append data to DOM as per your example... TBH I didn't thought about that and it now makes sense... cheers :)